# Use SQL to find out the highest frequency of the most common word

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I am using MySQL Workbench for my application (consisting of JavaScript and PHP). I have a SQL database that contains the tweets. I would like to query what is the highest frequency of the word from the tweets(sentence). I have done research that says to use count() to query but I still unable to get what I want.

Example dataset:

```
tweetsID |  Tweets                                           | DateTime
   1     | I can't wait to go to school tomorrow!            | 2014-07-18 12:00:00
   2     | My teacher saw me hanging out after school        | 2014-07-18 12:20:00
   3     | I had Pepper Lunch for my dinner                  | 2014-07-18 12:30:00
   4     | Something happened in my school omg               | 2014-07-18 12:40:00
   5     | This project is so hard!                          | 2014-07-18 12:50:00
```

Expected output:

```
Words   |frequency
  I     |2
 can't  |1
wait    |1
 to     |2
school  |3
tomorrow|1
  !     |2
 my     |3
had     |1
teacher |1
saw     |1
 me     |1
hanging |1
out     |1
after   |1
pepper  |1
lunch   |1
for     |1
dinner  |1
something|1
happened |1
in       |1
  omg    |1
 this    |1
project  |1
  is     |1
  so     |1
 hard    |1
```

I have create the sample data in the following link :

[ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b3f2/1 ]

Anyone can teach me or any reference for me to guide? Thank you in advance.

Comment: First of all, Workbench is a GUI tool for looking at the database directly. You won't be using it in your application. Secondly, try and show us what you've tried so far. Hint: the answer probably won't involve doing it purely in SQL but instead involve getting the data from your database and then using PHP or javascript to count the tokens.

Comment: How do you define a word? Is `cant't` to be treated as one word or 2 words?

Comment: @Kickstart Curiously, 'cannot' is one word in English, and so is its contraction. Donot ask me why. ;-)

Comment: Aye, but depends what the OP wants to treat it as. It is more of a issue if there are other bits of punctuation in places that make word boundaries difficult to determine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best bet is to do this in PHP. `array_count_values()` comes to mind.

Try this:

```
$sqlresults = array(
    "I can't wait to go to school tomorrow!",          
    "My teacher saw me hanging out after school",  
    "I had Pepper Lunch for my dinner",               
    "Something happened in my school omg",            
    "This project is so hard!"
);  

$arr = array();
foreach ($sqlresults as $str) {
    $arr = array_merge($arr, explode(' ', $str));    
}

$arr = array_count_values($arr);

print_r($arr);
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/kiHh44Tf)

---

*References:*

- [**array_count_values()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)
- [**array_merge()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)
- [**explode()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Definitely do this - don't attempt to count occurrences of words in a database - it will just get far too messy @StanislavL's answer - although it will work fine - will be a nightmare to maintain!! Not everything should be done with SQL!

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to refactor your DB.

I would introduce a separate table - `words (id, word)` and a relation table `tweet_to_word (tweet_id, word_id, word_count)` where you can keep all words for each tweet.

After that it would be a simple

```
select count(ttw.word_count)
from tweet_to_word ttw 
group by word_id
```

you can add ORDER BY to the select to find the most popular word

Comment: I have create the sample data in the following link :

[ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b3f2/1 ] maybe you can try on this :D thank you

Comment: In the fiddle you have to define 2 more tables and on each tweet parse the tweet writing the word id values in the tweet_to_word

Answer (score 0):

As a demonstration of how messy this could get, the following will almost do what you want in a single piece of SQL.

This firstly replace punctuation with spaces, then replaces 2 spaces with 1 space (several times). The idea of this is to give you a string which contains the words separated by a single space.

From this the number of words is calculated by comparing the length with the length with spaces replaced with nothing.

This is then cross joined with selects getting the numbers 0 to 9, which when cross joined gives you 1000 rows for each tweet, along with the numbers 0 to 999. This is then used with SUBSTRING_INDEX to get all the individual words. The number (from 0 to 999) is compared with the number of words in the tweet to avoid duplicating the last word.

Then this is just used for a normal COUNT / GROUP BY to get the word and count.

```
SELECT Words, COUNT(*) AS frequency
FROM
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Tweets, ' ', 1 + units.i + tens.i * 10 + hundreds.i * 100), ' ', -1) AS Words
    FROM (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) hundreds
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT Tweets,
                (LENGTH(Tweets) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Tweets, ' ', ''))) + 1 AS Tweets_Words
        FROM
        (
            SELECT TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Tweets, '(', ' '), ')', ' '), ',', ' '), '.', ' '), ';', ' '), ':', ' '), '?', ' '), '!', ' '), '{', ' '), '}', ' '), '  ', ' '), '  ', ' '), '  ', ' '), '  ', ' ')) AS Tweets
            FROM some_tweets
        ) sub0
    ) sub1
    WHERE Tweets_Words > (units.i + tens.i * 10 + hundreds.i * 100)
) sub2
GROUP BY Words
```

The replacement of double spaces with a single space can probably be removed, replacing it with a check that the resulting word is not '':-

```
SELECT Words, COUNT(*) AS frequency
FROM
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Tweets, ' ', 1 + units.i + tens.i * 10 + hundreds.i * 100), ' ', -1) AS Words
    FROM (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) hundreds
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT Tweets,
                (LENGTH(Tweets) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Tweets, ' ', ''))) + 1 AS Tweets_Words
        FROM
        (
            SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Tweets, '(', ' '), ')', ' '), ',', ' '), '.', ' '), ';', ' '), ':', ' '), '?', ' '), '!', ' '), '{', ' '), '}', ' ') AS Tweets
            FROM some_tweets
        ) sub0
    ) sub1
    WHERE Tweets_Words > (units.i + tens.i * 10 + hundreds.i * 100)
) sub2
WHERE Words != ''
GROUP BY Words
```

SQL fiddle for it here:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f28e5/1